# Visual studio keeps trying to recreate sql table instead of update

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

Im using visual studio to make a C# project with an sql database.  Im trying to update a table in the database and add a new column but whenever I hit the update button it tries to readd the table instead of updating it.  I have another table that I can update just fine.  What can I do to make it update the table?

Comment: Would like some comments as to why this is downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting Visual Studio fixed it.